# Which undefined behavior allows this optimization?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I'm working on a virtual machine which uses a typical Smi (small integer) encoding where integers are represented as tagged pointers. More precisely, pointers are tagged and integers are just shifted.

This is the same approach as taken by V8 and Dart: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/objects/smi.h#L17

In our implementation we have the following code for the Smi:

```cpp
// In smi.h

#include <stdint.h>

class Object {
 public:
  bool is_smi() const { return (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) & 0x1) == 0; }
};

class Smi : public Object {
 public:
  intptr_t value() const { return reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this) >> 1; }
  static Smi* from(intptr_t value) { return reinterpret_cast<Smi*>(value << 1); }
  static Smi* cast(Object* obj) { return static_cast<Smi*>(obj); }
};
```

With this setup, the following function is optimized by gcc 12.1.0 and `-O3` so that the 'if' is never taken when `o` has the Smi value 0.

```
// bad_optim.cc
#include "smi.h"

void bad_optim(Object* o) {
  if (!o->is_smi() || o == Smi::from(0)) {
    printf("in if\n");
  }
}
```

If I replace the 'if' line with the following code, the check works:

```
  if (!o->is_smi() || Smi::cast(o)->value() == 0) {
```

I'm guessing we are hitting an undefined behavior, but it's not clear to me which one.

Furthermore, it would be good to know whether there is a flag that warns about this behavior. Alternatively, maybe there is a flag to disable this optimization.

For completeness sake, here is a `main` that triggers the behavior. (Note that the `bad_optim` and `main` function must be compiled separately).

```
// main.cc
#include "smi.h"

void bad_optim(Object* o);

int main() {
  Smi* o = Smi::from(0);
  bad_optim(o);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the test being optimized away: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fKqqKqdTa

Comment: For me the test is reduced to just checking whether `o` is a smi or not. The value test is gone. I updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: My understanding is that any undefined behavior allows any optimization. Is the question actually "where is the undefined behavior in this code?" ?

Comment: FWIW both V8 and Dart VM have changed their code base to avoid representing tagged pointers directly as pointers to some structure (e.g. `Object*`) precisely because it hits this UB (which UBSAN was happy to constantly complain about). V8 design is described [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_w49sakC1XM1OptjTurBDqO86NE16FH8LwbeUAtrbCo/edit#heading=h.8wg7tpqbpt7m)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple: dereferencing invalid or null `o` would cause UB, so after the dereference, `o` supposedly can't be null.

Calling `is_smi()` counts as dereferencing, even if it actually doesn't access the memory.

Make `is_smi()` a free function (since this only applies to `this`, not pointer parameters). I'd also make `Object` an opaque struct (declared but not defined).

Comment: To add to this for anyone who didn't immediately see it, like myself: `Smi::from(0)` gives us null, so we are comparing `null` with a value that can never be null, hence the compiler completely eliminates that check since it can never pass.